# Transformation into a field with the result being a multiple of the determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Let $K$ be a field, $n \in N$ and d: $M_{n,n}(K) \to K $ an homogeneous and skew invariant transformation where $M_{n,n}(K)$ are the matrices over the field.

Show that there's a $d$ with $d = c * det$, with $c \in K$ and $det$ being the determinant.

Thanks in advance for any help! I've recently really started to like the determinant and it's practical uses and applications, but I yet struggle to fully understand all of them.

Comment: "skew invariant"?

Comment: Well, that's the term I got used to. It was defined as follows: if $v_1, ..., v_n \in K$, then a transformation f is skew invariant when $f(v_1, ..., v_i, v_j, ..., v_n) = f(v_1, ..., v_{i+j}, v_j, ..., v_n)$ for all $i, j$ with $1 ≤ i$, $j ≤ n$ and $i ≠ j$.

Comment: This is wrong on many levels. Do you mean that $f$ is $0$ whenever two rows are equal?

Comment: Probably homogeneous = multi-linear and skew-invariant = alternating. You still need to say that this is with respect to the columns (or with respect to the rows if that is what you mean; you cannot say both at once).